# How to check access to certain attributes of a model in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, model, rbac

Working with Yii framework I've got a question which I can not solve on my own.

How can I **nicely** check access to certain attributes of a model?

Context:

- I use RBAC, a user may have multiple roles at the same time
- I have a model with a bunch of attributes (for example, let's call it Profile)
- Some attributes are allowed to be edited by any registered user (`email`, `age`, `favorite color`, etc.), and some - only by the users with some specific role (`is_banned` - can be changed by moderator or administrator, `balance` - can be changed only by administrators, etc.)

What I've done already:
At the moment I see only one possible way to accomplish this task:

```
function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = Profile::model()->findByPk($id);

    if (!$this->user->checkAccess('editProfile')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }
    if (isset($_POST['is_banned'])) {
        if (!$this->user->checkAccess('toggleBan')) {
            unset($_POST['is_banned']);
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['balance'])) {
        if (!$this->user->checkAccess('changeBalance')) {
            unset($_POST['balance']);
        }
    }

    $model->setAttributes($_POST);
    $model->save();
}
```

Are there some better ways to solve such task? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using model scenarios (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/):

1. Add scenario condition to your model rules:

   ```
       public function rules()
       {
           return array(
               array('balance', 'integer', 'on' => 'admin'),
           );
       }
   ```
2. Set model scenario in controller:

   ```
       if ($this->user->checkAccess('admin')) {
           $model->scenario = 'admin';
       }
   ```

Now attributes that available by scenario are saved only.
Consider also using scenarios in search models.

Comment: As I know, Yii can not handle multiple scenarios at the same time. That's why this solution may not be applicable with RBAC as one user can have many roles.